# Application screen turns all black after resuming from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Repo for the same: https://github.com/tush4r/Phone

I have a little test application with no special features except some view elements, including field, button and so on. It is a separate storyboard module and gets called when the app is loaded.

Everything seems good here, till I push the app in the background by pressing the home button. Below are the screenshots for the same: One when the app is running, one after it went in the background and came back to the foreground.

I have no idea why is this happening? A couple of things implemented in the view controller are: Keyboard-hide on tap, UIButton, UITextField, and couple of alerts when the number entered is in the incorrect format.

[image: Screenshot when the App is running for the first time] [image: Screenshot when app came back to the foreground]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank You!

Xcode 7.3
Swift 2.2
iPhone 6s iOS 9.3

Comment: Well, you could at least provide a link to a sample project.

Comment: @Andrey Gordeev Thank you for mentioning that out. The app is on GitHub now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try definesPresentationContext to set true, works for me with similar problem.
In `viewDidLoad()`, add `definesPresentationContext = true`